# Make an IBOutlet UIImageView accessible from inside of a methods

Tags: iphone, c, ios, xcode, iboutlet

So, I have some IBOutlets set up for a bunch of UIImageView instances like this in my ViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey21;
```

In my implementation, I can access the IBOutlet when I'm in the viewDidLoad method like this:

```
[whiteKey21 setImage:image]; //image is declared and instantiated in viewDidLoad
```

My problem is that when I try to execute the same code in another methods, namely this one:

```
void noteUserCallback (void *inClientData, MusicSequence inSequence, MusicTrack inTrack, MusicTimeStamp inEventTime, const MusicEventUserData *inEventData, MusicTimeStamp inStartSliceBeat, MusicTimeStamp inEndSliceBeat)
{
    UserEvent* event = (UserEvent *)inEventData;
    UInt32 size = event->length;
    UInt32 note = event->playedNote;
    UInt32 timestamp = event->tStamp;
    NSLog(@"Size: %lu Note: %lu, Timestamp: %lu", size, note, timestamp);

    //Want to change the IBOutlet here.
}
```

It doesn't recognize the UIImages or UIImageViews that I declared in the header. I have a feeling that it is because this function is C-based due to the fact that that function has to interact with the MusicPlayer API. But I have no idea how to fix it? I tried making an Obj-C method that I could then call within the noteUserCallback function but it didn't recognize that either :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

***EDIT***

Here is the full code for the PracticeViewController.h and PracticeViewController.m

What I want to do is to set the image displayed by the UIImageViews (whiteKey21, etc.) from inside of the noteUserCallback function. The function is passed in some data (a UserEvent) whenever a user event is passed in the playback of the MIDI. This allows me to actively track what notes are being played. What I need to do, is to make a decision based on the "note" data in the UserEvent on which UIImageView to load an image into. But, I can't access the UIImageViews or the UIImages for that matter from inside the function for some reason. I have no problem access them in the other methods.

PracticeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Lesson.h"
#import "Note.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface PracticeViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Lesson *selectedLesson;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *practiceWindowTitle;
@property MusicPlayer player;

//Outlets for White Keys
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey21;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey23;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey24;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey26;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey28;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey29;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey31;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey33;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey35;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey36;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey38;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey40;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey41;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey43;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey45;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey47;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey48;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey50;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey52;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey53;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey55;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey57;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey59;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey60;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey62;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey64;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey65;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey67;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey69;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey71;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey72;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey74;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey76;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey77;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey79;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey81;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey83;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey84;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey86;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey88;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey89;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey91;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey93;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey95;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey96;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey98;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey100;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey101;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey103;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey105;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey107;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *whiteKey108;

//Outlets for Black Keys
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey22;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey25;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey27;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey30;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey32;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey34;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey37;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey39;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey42;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey44;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey46;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey49;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey51;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey54;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey56;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey58;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey61;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey63;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey66;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey68;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey70;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey73;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey75;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey78;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey80;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey82;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey85;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey87;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey90;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey92;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey94;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey97;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey99;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey102;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey104;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *blackKey106;

// Key Highlight Images
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightA;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightB;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightD;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightE;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightF;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightG;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *highlightH;

- (IBAction)practiceLesson:(id)sender;

@end
```

PracticeViewController.m

```
#import "PracticeViewController.h"

@interface PracticeViewController ()

@end

@implementation PracticeViewController
@synthesize blackKey22;
@synthesize blackKey25;
@synthesize blackKey27;
@synthesize blackKey30;
@synthesize blackKey32;
@synthesize blackKey34;
@synthesize blackKey37;
@synthesize blackKey39;
@synthesize blackKey42;
@synthesize blackKey44;
@synthesize blackKey46;
@synthesize blackKey49;
@synthesize blackKey51;
@synthesize blackKey54;
@synthesize blackKey56;
@synthesize blackKey58;
@synthesize blackKey61;
@synthesize blackKey63;
@synthesize blackKey66;
@synthesize blackKey68;
@synthesize blackKey70;
@synthesize blackKey73;
@synthesize blackKey75;
@synthesize blackKey78;
@synthesize blackKey80;
@synthesize blackKey82;
@synthesize blackKey85;
@synthesize blackKey87;
@synthesize blackKey90;
@synthesize blackKey92;
@synthesize blackKey94;
@synthesize blackKey97;
@synthesize blackKey99;
@synthesize blackKey102;
@synthesize blackKey104;
@synthesize blackKey106;
@synthesize whiteKey21;
@synthesize whiteKey23;
@synthesize whiteKey24;
@synthesize whiteKey26;
@synthesize whiteKey28;
@synthesize whiteKey29;
@synthesize whiteKey31;
@synthesize whiteKey33;
@synthesize whiteKey35;
@synthesize whiteKey36;
@synthesize whiteKey38;
@synthesize whiteKey40;
@synthesize whiteKey41;
@synthesize whiteKey43;
@synthesize whiteKey45;
@synthesize whiteKey47;
@synthesize whiteKey48;
@synthesize whiteKey50;
@synthesize whiteKey52;
@synthesize whiteKey53;
@synthesize whiteKey55;
@synthesize whiteKey57;
@synthesize whiteKey59;
@synthesize whiteKey60;
@synthesize whiteKey62;
@synthesize whiteKey64;
@synthesize whiteKey65;
@synthesize whiteKey67;
@synthesize whiteKey69;
@synthesize whiteKey71;
@synthesize whiteKey72;
@synthesize whiteKey74;
@synthesize whiteKey76;
@synthesize whiteKey77;
@synthesize whiteKey79;
@synthesize whiteKey81;
@synthesize whiteKey83;
@synthesize whiteKey84;
@synthesize whiteKey86;
@synthesize whiteKey88;
@synthesize whiteKey89;
@synthesize whiteKey91;
@synthesize whiteKey93;
@synthesize whiteKey95;
@synthesize whiteKey96;
@synthesize whiteKey98;
@synthesize whiteKey100;
@synthesize whiteKey101;
@synthesize whiteKey103;
@synthesize whiteKey105;
@synthesize whiteKey107;
@synthesize whiteKey108;

@synthesize selectedLesson, practiceWindowTitle, player, highlightA, highlightB, highlightC, highlightD, highlightE, highlightF, highlightG, highlightH;

// Implement the UserEvent structure.

typedef struct UserEvent {
    UInt32 length;
    UInt32 typeID;
    UInt32 trackID;
    MusicTimeStamp tStamp;
    MusicTimeStamp dur;
    int playedNote;
} UserEvent;

// Implement the UserCallback function.

void noteUserCallback (void *inClientData, MusicSequence inSequence, MusicTrack inTrack, MusicTimeStamp inEventTime, const MusicEventUserData *inEventData, MusicTimeStamp inStartSliceBeat, MusicTimeStamp inEndSliceBeat)
{
    PracticeViewController *pvc = (__bridge PracticeViewController *)inClientData;

    UserEvent* event = (UserEvent *)inEventData;
    UInt32 size = event->length;
    UInt32 note = event->playedNote;
    UInt32 timestamp = event->tStamp;
    NSLog(@"Size: %lu Note: %lu, Timestamp: %lu", size, note, timestamp);

    switch (note) {
        case 60:
            [pvc.whiteKey21 setImage:pvc.highlightA];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.practiceWindowTitle.title = selectedLesson.titleAndSubtitle;

    // Load in the images for the glow.
    highlightA = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysA.png"];
    highlightB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysB.png"];
    highlightC = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysC.png"];
    highlightD = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysD.png"];
    highlightE = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysE.png"];
    highlightF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysF.png"];
    highlightG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_blackKey.png"];
    highlightH = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glow_whiteKeysH.png"];

    // Create player, sequence, left/right hand tracks, and iterator.

    NewMusicPlayer(&player);
    MusicSequence sequence;
    NewMusicSequence(&sequence);
    MusicTrack rightHand;
    MusicTrack leftHand;
    MusicEventIterator iterator;

    // Load in MIDI file.

    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] init];
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedLesson.midiFilename ofType:@"mid"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    MusicSequenceFileLoad(sequence, (__bridge CFURLRef)url, 0, kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks);

    // Get the right and left hand tracks from the sequence.

    int rightHandIndex = 0;
    //int leftHandIndex = 1;

    MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(sequence, rightHandIndex, &rightHand); //Get right hand.
    //MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(sequence, leftHandIndex, leftHand); //Get left hand.

    //Iterate through the right hand track and add user events.

    Boolean hasNextEvent = false;
    Boolean hasEvent = false;

    NewMusicEventIterator(rightHand, &iterator);
    MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasEvent);
    MusicEventIteratorHasNextEvent(iterator, &hasNextEvent);

    while (hasNextEvent == true) {
        MusicTimeStamp timestamp = 0;
        MusicEventType eventType = 0;
        const void *eventData = NULL;
        int note;
        MusicTimeStamp duration;

        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator, &timestamp, &eventType, &eventData, NULL);

        if (eventType == kMusicEventType_MIDINoteMessage) {
            MIDINoteMessage *noteMessage = (MIDINoteMessage *)eventData;
            note = noteMessage->note;
            duration = noteMessage->duration;
            UserEvent event;

            // Hacky way of doing this...Change one we get the UserEvent class figured out.

            event.length = 0;
            event.length = sizeof(UserEvent);

            event.playedNote = note;

            event.tStamp = timestamp;

            MusicEventUserData* data = (MusicEventUserData *)&event;
            MusicTrackNewUserEvent(rightHand, timestamp, data);
        }

        MusicEventIteratorHasNextEvent(iterator, &hasNextEvent);
        MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iterator);
    }

    MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(sequence, noteUserCallback, (__bridge void*)self);

    MusicPlayerSetSequence(player, sequence);
    MusicPlayerPreroll(player);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setPracticeWindowTitle:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey21:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey23:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey24:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey26:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey28:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey29:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey31:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey33:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey35:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey36:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey38:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey40:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey41:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey43:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey45:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey47:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey48:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey50:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey52:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey53:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey55:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey57:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey59:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey60:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey62:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey64:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey65:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey67:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey69:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey71:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey72:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey74:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey76:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey77:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey79:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey81:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey83:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey84:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey86:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey88:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey89:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey91:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey93:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey95:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey96:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey98:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey100:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey100:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey101:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey103:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey105:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey107:nil];
    [self setWhiteKey108:nil];
    [self setBlackKey22:nil];
    [self setBlackKey25:nil];
    [self setBlackKey27:nil];
    [self setBlackKey30:nil];
    [self setBlackKey32:nil];
    [self setBlackKey34:nil];
    [self setBlackKey37:nil];
    [self setBlackKey39:nil];
    [self setBlackKey42:nil];
    [self setBlackKey44:nil];
    [self setBlackKey46:nil];
    [self setBlackKey49:nil];
    [self setBlackKey51:nil];
    [self setBlackKey54:nil];
    [self setBlackKey56:nil];
    [self setBlackKey58:nil];
    [self setBlackKey61:nil];
    [self setBlackKey63:nil];
    [self setBlackKey66:nil];
    [self setBlackKey68:nil];
    [self setBlackKey70:nil];
    [self setBlackKey73:nil];
    [self setBlackKey75:nil];
    [self setBlackKey78:nil];
    [self setBlackKey80:nil];
    [self setBlackKey82:nil];
    [self setBlackKey85:nil];
    [self setBlackKey87:nil];
    [self setBlackKey90:nil];
    [self setBlackKey92:nil];
    [self setBlackKey94:nil];
    [self setBlackKey97:nil];
    [self setBlackKey99:nil];
    [self setBlackKey102:nil];
    [self setBlackKey104:nil];
    [self setBlackKey106:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)practiceLesson:(id)sender {
    MusicPlayerStart(player);
}
@end
```

***EDIT***

The code relating to MusicSequenceSetUserCallback. This is declared in the MusicPlayer API (AudioToolbox/MusicPlayer.h):

```
/*!
    @typedef MusicSequenceUserCallback
@discussion See MusicSequenceSetUserCallback
*/

typedef void (*MusicSequenceUserCallback)(  void                        *inClientData,
                                            MusicSequence               inSequence,
                                            MusicTrack                  inTrack,
                                            MusicTimeStamp              inEventTime,
                                            const MusicEventUserData    *inEventData,
                                            MusicTimeStamp              inStartSliceBeat,
                                            MusicTimeStamp              inEndSliceBeat);


/*!
    @function   MusicSequenceSetUserCallback
    @abstract   Establish a user callback for a sequence
    @discussion This call is used to register (or remove if inCallback is NULL) a callback
                that the MusicSequence will call for ANY UserEvents that are added to any of the
                tracks of the sequence.

                If there is a callback registered, then UserEvents will be chased when
                MusicPlayerSetTime is called. In that case the inStartSliceBeat and inEndSliceBeat
                will both be the same value and will be the beat that the player is chasing too.

                In normal cases, where the sequence data is being scheduled for playback, the
                following will apply:
                    inStartSliceBeat <= inEventTime < inEndSliceBeat

                The only exception to this is if the track that owns the MusicEvent is looping.
                In this case the start beat will still be less than the end beat (so your callback
                can still determine that it is playing, and what beats are currently being scheduled),
                however, the inEventTime will be the original time-stamped time of the user event. 
    @param      inSequence      the sequence
    @param      inCallback      the callback
    @param      inClientData    client (user supplied) data provided back to the callback when it is called by the sequence
*/
extern OSStatus
MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(   MusicSequence               inSequence,
                                MusicSequenceUserCallback   inCallback,
                                void*                       inClientData)       __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_3,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused from this being C code. But it would be helpful if you put the failing actual code in there rather than the comment.

Comment: Is your `UIImageView` a property of `UserEvent`?

Comment: @Jim. Hey, I added the full code.

Comment: @Saphrosit. No, the UIImageViews are just instance variables declared in the header of my view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all CoreAudio callbacks you have a "user data" parameter, which is probably in your callback the `void *inClientData` one, which allows to pass to the callback ANY object the user wants to pass.
In your case when you register the callback, e.g. when you create an Audio Queue Input, you pass in the long list of parameters the name of the callback but you can also pass the address of the user data structure you prefer that will be sent to the callback using the `inClientData` pointer mentioned before. In your case what you can pass is the address of your class instance that contains the UIImageViews (e.g. if your class instance is "myObj" then you will pass `&myObj`).

So inside the callback you will dereference it in this way:

```
MyObject *myObject = (MyObject *)inClientData;
```

Now in your code you set the MusicSequenceCallback in this way:

```
MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(sequence, noteUserCallback, NULL);
```

the 3rd parameter is `void *inClientData` and it is this data that is passed as first parameter of the callback. So instead of NULL you must pass your object containing all the UIImageViews you need to use:

```
MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(sequence, noteUserCallback, myObject);
```

and then you will be able to use any obj-c method on this obj instance. The pointer to this object will be passed to the callback and then you will just need to dereference it inside the callback.

Comment: I don't think that would work in my case as I have to pass in a UserEvent object to inClientData (please see updated code).

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working. The fact that I can access my UIImageViews and UIImages in viewDidLoad and the other methods but not in noteUserCallback is baffling. I must just be missing something simple...but what?

Comment: see my updated answer; the problem is that you're passing NULL in the set user callback, while you should pass your object that contains the image views. This is the only way CoreAudio callbacks talk with the user context.

Comment: Hey, so what you're saying is I have to encapsulate my UIImages and UIImageViews into its own class (let's call it HighlightImages), instantiate that in viewDidLoad, then pass that (e.g. highlightImagesInstance) into my MusicSequenceSetUserCallback. Then, in my noteUserCallback function, I have to dereference that (e.g. HighlightImages highlightImagesInstance = (HighlightImages *) hImages;) (like that?). Then I could call whatever obj-C methods I like with it? E.g., I would need to: [whiteKey21 setImage:highlightA]; (where whiteKey21 is my UIImageView and highlightA is my UIImage).

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Usually the convention is to pass a struct as user data but of course in Obj-C you can use an object instead. Some people prefer to keep passing a struct and simply add one or more objects as fields of the struct. Besides if you consider that the class that defines the callback is probably the object which is mostly interested to the callback, it is perfectly legitimate, and it is common practice in fact, to pass it and then dereference the object as "self", so you can call methods inside the callback with [self myMethod] (check-out Apple CoreAudio examples)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I'll try it out when I get a change and then report back on my progress :)

Comment: Hey, I removed all of my UIImages and IBOutlets for my UIImageViews from my PracticeViewController.h and placed them into my ImageHighlights.h but I'm having a problem. When I try to connect my IBOutlets to my UIImageViews in Interface Builder (storyboard) they won't connect. I've imported the ImageHighlights.h into my PracticeViewController.h and I can instantiate an instance of the ImageHighlights object within my PracticeViewController.m but for some reason, I can't connect the IBOutlets from the ImageHighlights.h to my UIImageViews. I'm probably just missing something silly.

Comment: By the way, my ImageHighlights.h is a subclass of NSObject. Not sure if I should have made it something else?

Comment: Why you don't pass the whole PracticeViewController? I don't think you need to refactor your code, just pass the whole class and then dereference it: PracticeViewController *pvc = (PracticeViewController *)inData;

Comment: Well, there's an idea. I'll give that a shot and see if it works.

Comment: So I tried it but I can't seem to get it to work. Am I casting something wrong? I've posted the code I have so far.

Comment: You must pass "self", that is the real live instance and not a generic pvc which, in  your code, is clearly nil:
MusicSequenceSetUserCallback(sequence, noteUserCallback, self);
as self (not &self) is of type PracticeViewController then you must, inside the callback, dereference it as: PractiveViewController *pvc = (PracticeViewController *)inData;

Comment: That makes sense. I tried to pass in self though and it said that I had to used a bridged cast to do it. So I tried to bridge it (__bridge void)self but then it told me it was an invalid conversion between PracticeViewController and void. Any suggestions?

Comment: So I tried passing (__bridge void*)self into MusicSequenceSetUsercallback and casting like this in noteUserCallback:     PracticeViewController *pvc = (__bridge PracticeViewController *)inClientData;
I didn't get any errors but it still doesn't work :( I updated the code to show what I did.

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong in the first place but I passed in self, bridged it to a void* and then dereferenced back to a view controller class in the function with a bridge and it worked great :)